# Excel autocomplete not working consistently

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, autocomplete

I am using Excel 2010 to work on a large scale data entry project that involves thousands of different names.  All these data are organized into a single column, and there is more often than not a large variety in names as these are from all over the U.S. and Canada.
An example can be seen here:

`Bill Leighton, Jr.
Les Siebert
Andrew Kosiski
Tom Svoboda
David Livingston
Andy Wilkinson
Matt Buller
Micah Veleba
Dwayne Pospisil
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
Jase Kaser
Les Siebert
Philip Loseke
Tom Svoboda
Alex Humphrey
Andrew Kosiski
John Bridges
Micah Veleba
Denton Buller
Tom Svoboda`

The ampersands represent, in this hypothetical scenario, the line between data entered on Monday (above the ampersands) and those entered on Tuesday (below the ampersands).  For some reason, when I enter "Les Seibert" on Monday, I can autocomplete his name by typing (however many letters as necessary; a name like "Les" is very rare in my data) "Les" and the "Siebert" will come up.  I can hit Enter and move on with things.  However, on Tuesday, when I come across ol' "Les Siebert" autocomplete won't fill in the rest of his name; I have to type the entire "Les Siebert."  Yet I will find "Les Siebert" in my list of names when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>.

But why does autocomplete stop working on data I entered on previous days/session?  Why doesn't it remember "Les Siebert" on Tuesday as well as Monday?  Is there anyway, without using Macros, to make Excel remember stuff on a day-to-day basis?  My other Excel files remember my data, so what could I have done to make this one not work anymore?

Comment: Do you have an actual separator (line,  empty row...) between the data entered in separate days?

Comment: To answer your question, I don't.  I just did that for clarification.

Comment: I could only guess that due to the large number of data you have Excel is lazy and includes only new data into its index. You may try saving your file as .xlsb.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I tried saving as .xlsb, and that sadly didn't work either.  Why can I see the values when I press Alt + down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it wasn't pretty, but I was able to confirm that Excel does indeed forget after so many entries and can only remember the most recent entries.  So, the answer to my question is that I have too much data for autocomplete to handle.

The following links are all I found addressing this issue:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/auto-complete-limited-to-120-rows/f1a82077-74c9-4050-9dd3-76662e283d81?auth=1
https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/39818-limit-autocomplete.html

Answer (score -1):

It only autocompletes when there is only a single match for what you've typed. So in your example if there was a `Les Sieberd` you will never get autocomplete suggestions no matter how much of the name you type.

Comment: But this is NOT the issue I am having... my point is that it's not autocompleting even for unique values.  There is *no* equivalent of `Les Sieberd` as you suggest.  The issue is something other than this.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is the "blank" cell, which is interrupting autocomplete. Autocomplete only works between blanks. You have two options:

1. Avoid blank cells (use any string instead)
2. Add a left column and fill it with anything (remember, no blank cells). In this way Excel use your Names column AND your left column to look for a blank to interrupt Autocomplete funtcion.

Regards!

Comment: There is no blank cell. -1